# pysnmp - nextCmd - not retrieving next element

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysnmp

I'm new to python. I'm trying to understand the usage of pysnmp.

I tried the following:

```
import asyncio
from pysnmp.hlapi.asyncio import *
from pysnmp import debug

@asyncio.coroutine
def run():
    snmpEngine = SnmpEngine()
    while True:
        errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = yield from nextCmd(
            snmpEngine,
            CommunityData('public', mpModel=1),
            UdpTransportTarget(('giga-int-2', 161)),
            ContextData(),
            ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1')),
            lexicographicMode=False
        )

        if errorIndication:
            print(errorIndication)
            break
        elif errorStatus:
            print('%s at %s' % (
                errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1][0] or '?')
            )
        else:
            for varBind in varBinds:
                for v in varBind:
                    print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in v]))

    snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.closeDispatcher()

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(run())
```

As result I get always the same interface. What's wrong? Why is it not retrieving the next element?

```
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.31.1.1.1.1.1 = sc0
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.31.1.1.1.1.1 = sc0
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.31.1.1.1.1.1 = sc0
```

Comment: Try another OID. It seems your code works, but you are querying for the device name which all time is the same

Comment: What I want achieve is the same output of  snmpwalk -v2c -cpublic giga-int-2 1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1
IF-MIB::ifName.1 = STRING: sc0
    IF-MIB::ifName.2 = STRING: sl0  ...

Comment: In this case you should loop through OIDs 1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1, 1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.2, 1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.3 etc., i think.

Comment: How does the code looks like? I thought nextCmd would do this for me.

Comment: @Celio: I am just wondering if you managed to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

this works. But I would like to avoid an explicit next() and it's not suitable for asyncio

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *
from pysnmp import debug
g = nextCmd(
    SnmpEngine(),
    CommunityData('public', mpModel=1),
    UdpTransportTarget(('giga-int-2', 161)),
    ContextData(),
    ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1')),
    lexicographicMode=False
)

while True:
    try:
        errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(g);
        if errorIndication:
            print(errorIndication)
        elif errorStatus:
            print('%s at %s' % (errorStatus.prettyPrint(), errorIndex and     varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1][0] or '?'))
        else:
            for name, val in varBinds:
                print('%s = %s' % (name.prettyPrint(), val.prettyPrint()))
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Comment: Will this solution be async

Answer (score 1):

Inside you loop you are sending a *single* SNMP GETNEXT command and receive a response. You are sending the same request for the same OID at all times, that explains why you are consistently receiving the same answer. ;-)

To "walk" your SNMP agent, on each iteration, you need to send request for the OID you just received in response on the previous iteration until you decide to stop (or run out of OIDs at the agent).

Here is my not tested code to give you an idea:

```
start_oid = ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1'))
end_oid = ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.10'))
oid = start_oid

while oid < end_oid:
    errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = yield from nextCmd(
        snmpEngine,
        CommunityData('public', mpModel=1),
        UdpTransportTarget(('giga-int-2', 161)),
        ContextData(),
        oid
    )
    # ...omitted error checking...
    varBind = varBinds[0]
    # here we replacing the `oid` that goes into the next request
    oid, value = varBind
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code will work for you. It is async and not contains explicit calls.

```
import asyncio
from pysnmp.hlapi.asyncio import *


@asyncio.coroutine
def getone(snmpEngine, target):
    errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = yield from getCmd(
        snmpEngine,
        CommunityData('public', mpModel=1),
        UdpTransportTarget(('giga-int-2', 161)),
        ContextData(),
        target
    )

    if errorIndication:
        print(errorIndication)
    elif errorStatus:
        print('%s at %s' % (
            errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
            errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1][0] or '?'
        )
              )
    else:
        for varBind in varBinds:
            print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))


snmpEngine = SnmpEngine()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(
    asyncio.wait([getone(snmpEngine, ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.' + str(n)))) for n in range(1,254)])
```

Comment: It works, but does not stop when all oids under 1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1.X are read. It continues with 1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.2.x and so on

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution build using @Ilya Etingof 's answer. Functions are in *some host handler* class.

```
def inc_oid(self, oid):
    _oid = oid.split('.')
    lastint = int(_oid[-1])
    _oid[-1] = str(lastint + 1)
    return '.'.join(_oid)


async def snmp_walk_async(self, oid):
    resultstr = ''
    endoid = self.inc_oid(oid)
    while True:
        (errorIndication, 
        errorStatus, 
        errorIndex, 
        varBinds)  = await nextCmd(
                    self.snmpengine,
                    CommunityData(self.community, mpModel=0),
                    UdpTransportTarget((self.host, 161)),
                    ContextData(),
                    ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(oid)),
                    lexicographicMode=False)

        if errorIndication:
            print(errorIndication)
            break
        elif errorStatus:
            print('%s at %s' % (errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                                errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1][0] or '?'))
            break

        else:
            varBind = varBinds[0][0]
            oid, value = varBind
            oid = str(oid)

            if oid >= endoid:
                break

            for varBind in varBinds:
                resultstr += ' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]) + '\n'

    return resultstr
```